# What is an example of a set $A$ such that $\bar{A}\neq Int(A)\cup A'$

Tags: real-analysis

Given the question in the title, doesn't it mean that $A=Int(A)\cap A'$?

$Int(A)$ being the interior of $A$ and $A'$ being the set of all accumulation point of $A$.

Lost on where to even begin. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: No, it means exactly what it says. Try an open interval in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You can’t *let* $\operatorname{cl}A=(0,1)$: that isn’t a closed subset of $\Bbb R$. If you want the closure of $A$ *not* to be $\operatorname{int}A\cup A'$, you need a different kind of example: you need a set $A$ that has a point $x$ that is neither an accumulation point of $A$ nor in the interior of $A$. That means that $x$ has to be isolated: it’s in $A$, but it has an open nbhd that contains no other point of $A$. Can you think of such a subset of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: How about $A:=1/z \cup 0$ where $z\in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: The title and question text are inconsistent.

Comment: @ozarka: Assuming that you mean $A=\left\{\frac1z:z\in\Bbb Z\right\}\cup\{0\}$, yes, that would work. It’s already closed, so it is $\operatorname{cl}A$, $0$ is its only accumulation point, and its interior is empty, so $\operatorname{int}A\cup A'=\{0\}\ne\operatorname{cl}A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. I can't believe I got that right. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @ozarka: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither $\overline{A}=\operatorname{int}(A) \cup A'$ nor $A=\operatorname{int}(A) \cap A'$ need to hold.

Take $A=\{1/n \mid n>0\} \cup \{0\}$.  This has empty interior and $A'=\{0\}$, but $\operatorname{int}(A)\cup A'=\{0\}$ and $\operatorname{int}(A)\cap A'=\emptyset\neq A$.

Comment: @ozarka You had written $A= \operatorname{int}(A)\cap A'$ in the body of your question.  If you had meant $\overline{A}= \operatorname{int}(A)\cap A'$, then you'll see that that also does not hold ($A$ is closed, so $\overline{A}=A$.)

Comment: Apologies, that was my mistake.